# Delta-Testing, test only changed parts of the "infected" code-base

Tags: java, performance, continuous-integration, integration-testing

I'd like to speed up our integrationtest-suite. It is long running. Too long. As everyone knows not every change has an impact on everything. So why not just test components which are influenced by the change?

From [infinitest](http://infinitest.github.com/) I know, it is just running the related tests, so why not do the same on ... jenkins.

Is there any tool, what this is doing?

1000 Tests, 1 change, 10 related and only these 10 tests should run.

Related could be defined as related in code-coverage way.

I search for tools that are running tests in an analogous way to delta debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will be interested in the following:

- [ddexpr - "Evaluating delta debugging on real regression bugs"](http://code.google.com/p/ddexpr/)
- [iregression - "A simple and practical tool for debugging software regressions"](http://code.google.com/p/iregression/)

Comment: this is not for java, sry, I did not mentioned above, now I did

Comment: You said it's not for java then added the java tag?